# Json to Google chart dataTable JQuery

Tags: jquery, json, google-visualization

I have records in JSON format

```
"returns":[{
    "apr": 0.779,
    "aug": 0.000,
    "dec": 0.000,
    "feb": 1.524,
    "jan": -0.570,
    "jul": 0.329,
    "jun": 0.000,
    "mar": 1.460,
    "may": 0.000,
    "nov": 0.000,
    "oct": 0.000,
    "ret": 3.557,
    "sep": 0.000,
    "vol": 2.649,
    "year": 2017
}, {
    "apr": 0.000,
    "aug": 0.974,
    "dec": -0.149,
    "feb": 0.000,
    "jan": 0.000,
    "jul": 0.236,
    "jun": 0.000,
    "mar": 0.000,
    "may": 0.000,
    "nov": 0.000,
    "oct": 0.898,
    "ret": 1.488,
    "sep": -0.471,
    "vol": 1.428,
    "year": 2016
}]
```

Now I want to display in Google Line chart

Can any one help me to display in Google Line Chart?

[Expecting Google Line chart like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzMHw.png)

Comment: yes you are right WhiteHat , i want a line each year except the "ret" and "vol"(do not worry about it) it is not necessary to display. No I want to display "text" not "numbers"

Comment: Since you want a line for each year, you'll need to put the data for each year in a separate column.  So using arrayToDataTable, [['month', 'year2017', 'year2016'], ['apr', 0.779, 0.0], ['aug', 0, 0.974], ...]  But you will probably want to sort months not alphabetically, but by their proper order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have declared some variables for need. Here "returns" is the JSON data which is I am having (given above sample in Question)

```
   // var returns ===> JSON data
    var dataLength=null;
    var keyCount=null;
    var month=["jan","feb","mar","apr","may","jun","jul","aug","sep","oct","nov","dec"];
```

Get the details from my json like below..

```
if( returns.length>0){ 
        dataLength=returns.length;/// Get Total number of Records ==> returns
        keyCount=Object.keys(returns[0]).length;/// Get Total number of key values having each object inside "returns"
    }
```

Adding columns into DataTable ..

```
const data = new google.visualization.DataTable();    
 data.addColumn('string', 'Mois');
  for(var i=0;i<dataLength;i++){
        data.addColumn('number',returns[i]["year"]); /// Adding each year as Column into Datatable
    }
```

And I am created temporary array to add data into DataTable "data"

```
for(var a=0;a<month.length;a++){ // Loop to iterate to get all MONTH values
        var arr = []; /// Declaring Empty array
        arr.push(month_Fr[a]);/// Push Month name (French) into Array 
        for(var b=0;b<dataLength;b++){ /// Loop to iterate to get all YEAR values
            monthValue=returns[b][month[a]]; /// Get value of each row object 
            arr.push(monthValue); /// Push object value into Array
        }
        data.addRow(arr); // Adding Row into Datatable
    }
```

creating chart elements

```
const chartOptions = {
      chart: {
        title: 'Performance'
      },
      curveType: 'function',
      width: 900,
      height: 500
    };
    const chart = new google.charts.Line($('#chart')[0]);
    chart.draw(data, chartOptions);
```

Finally my Line chart is :: click below link.

[Line chart from JSON Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXvic.png)

Comment: I need to display Months in French so I have added an array with name month_Fr and got month names from array French   `var month_Fr=["Jan","Fev","Mar","Avr","Mai","Jui","Juil","Aou","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];`